# How to create a minimize button with pysimplegui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm creating a UI for my application and wanted to remove windows minimize and close buttons and add my own, i've added a close button but i don't know what function should I set the button to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `close()` method is used for that. I don't what kinda button is your one, but you can call this method on your window object when button is pressed.

```
if event == "Button":

      window.close()
```